# insert a line in csv file

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk, terminal

I have a  huge csv file (on order of terabytes).

Now, I want to insert one row which is a header to the the top.

For example if input.csv looks like this:

```
 1,2,3,4
 22,3,23,1
```

I want it to look like

```
id1,id2,id3,id4
 1,2,3,4
 and so on
```

How do i do this from shell, terminal, awk, bash?/

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In place, using sed:

```
sed -i 1i"id1,id2,id3,id4" file.csv
```

edit:

As @Ed Morton points out, using sed with the `-i` switch sed edits the file in place, and can therefore be dangerous when editing large files. If you supply a prefix after the `-i` option then sed creates a backup. So something like this would be safer:

```
sed -i.bak 1i"id1,id2,id3,id4" file.csv
```

The original file will then be located in `file.csv.bak`

Comment: I would definitely not do that with such a large file. sed is creating a tmp file on the fly - if it fails to find the space for it I would not be surprised if you lost the contents of your original file. Just use `cmd file > tmp && mv tmp file` and you know you're safe.

Comment: @Ed: you're right, this is not particularly safe for very large files like the one in question. I have edited my answer to provide a safer alternative, still using sed.

Answer (score 19):

This is that simple as :

```
{ echo "id1,id2,id3,id4"; cat file.csv; } > newfile.csv
```

using simple shell concatenation.

**EDIT**

after discussion thread below, I propose this :

- create a file with your header, said `head.txt`

Then :

```
cat head.txt file.csv > newfile.csv
```

Comment: Is there a way not to "echo" the whole contents of the file.. for some reason it is pritining all the contents of the file.. and its really huge file?

Comment: @Fraz: there is no easy way to do this, even when doing it without a temporary file (like in my answer). The problem is that you are physically having to shift all of the data in your file down by 16 bytes.

Comment: oh.. ok.. i am getting an error that command not found.. its a long query.. so here it is
 { echo "mkey1,merchant_id,flag, default,E1,E2,E3,E4,E5,E7,E8,E9,E10,E11,E12,E13,E14,E15,E16,E17,E18,E19,E20,E21,E22,E23,E24,E25,E26,E27,E28,E29,E30,E31,E32,E33,E34,E35,E36,E37,E38,E39,E40,E41,E42,I1,I2,I4,I5,I6,I7,I8,I9,I10,I11,I12,I13,I14,I15,I16,I17,I18,I19,I20,I21,I22,I23,I24,I25,I26,I27,I28,I29,I30,I31,I32,I33,I34,I35,I36,I37,I38,I39,I40,I41,I42,I43,I44,I46,I47,I48,I50,I51,I52,I53,I54,I55,I56,O1,O2,O3,O4,O5,O6,O7,O8,O9,benchmark_score,julian,weight " ; cat prepared_input.csv ; } > mahout_input.csv

Comment: @LeeNetherton : `sed -i` is definitely creating a temporary file. Goo luck to all.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit.** When I wrote this answer, I overlooked the "terabyte" part of the question. Hence, *do not use the method presented here*. I still leave this post, as it advertises the use of this wonderful tool, `ed`, the standard text editor.

As usual, `ed` is the standard text editor. The solution using `sed -i` doesn't, as it mentions, "edit the file in place". Instead, it outputs its content to a temporary file, and then renames this file to the original one. That's really not good for large files!

Using `ed` instead really edits the file. Something along the following lines:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="input.csv"

{
ed -s "$file" <<EOF
1
i
id1,id2,id3,id4
.
wq
EOF
} > /dev/null
```

Explanation: `1` goes to the first line, `i` goes into insert mode, then we insert `id1,id2,id3,id4` then `.` to go back to normal mode, and `wq` to write and quit.

With this method, you're really editing the file and it's twice faster than the sed method. Also, `ed` is known to be "large file safe"!

Done.

Comment: It's not true that no buffer is created. `ed` will read the whole file into a buffer and zap the original file before writing it's buffer to that file. It will be very slow and is not safe.

Comment: If you know that then you shouldn't mislead the OP by saying "No temporary file created, **no buffers**, no nothing!".

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way, you're going to have to rewrite the file. Probably the safest way is to

```
 ( echo "id1,id2,id3,id4" ; cat file ) > newFile && rm file
```

IHTH

Comment: my experience is that { .... } is effectively a subshell. So it's 1/2 of 1, .5 of another. Good luck.

Comment: No, `( )` is a subshell while `{ }` is a regroupment.

Comment: @shellter: Is there a way not to "echo" the whole contents of the file.. for some reason it is pritining all the contents of the file.. and its really huge file?

Comment: sorry, I'm aware of the difference between the two, my personal code uses `{ .. }` whenenver it can, but in the case of a multi-terabyte file, I don't see that there would a a meaningful performance difference. My experince, when using `ptree` on `{ ... }` groupings showed that a new process was created to manage the output. I don't have the time now to create a test case to revisit this. Good luck to all.

Comment: @Fraz: No way. that's why I wrote "no easy way, you're going to have to rewrite the file". A known limitation (feature) to the Unix filesystem model ;-) .Sorry. Good luck to all.

Comment: @Fraz: you can do it without echo or cat, but only using some other tool/approach that uses some kind of buffer (e.g. "ed") that will probably take longer to run than the above and will be more likely to fail spectacularly when you least expect it.

Answer (score -2):

echo "id1,id2,id3,id4" >> data.csv

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow! :) This is also a cool shortcut, but inserts the provided line *at the end* of the file.